# opencsv.parseLine on JSON return with missing "

Tags: java, parsing, opencsv

I am trying to parse a field in JSON as String with following command.

```
List<string> arguments = Arrays.asList(new  CSVParser().parseLine(message));
```

and a few " are missing.

```
message = "{"totalResults":138,"work_search:work_hr_resources":1}"

arguments[0] = {totalResults":138,work_search:work_hr_resources":1}
```

Is it a bug or there is a workaround it?

Comment: Looks like open csv parse line is doing that. What's your original requirement. Is it possible to use other than open csv?

Comment: Could you recommend any other csv tools. I tried with CSVParser, but getting no record even I followed their instruction. /* CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(message,CSVFormat.DEFAULT);

        List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<>();

        for (CSVRecord record : parser) {
            arguments.add(record.toString());
        }*/

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it resolved by adding a space just before the \" and it resolved my issue. So adding a space in front of preceding ". Everything looks good.

```
message= "{ "totalResults":138, "workday_search:workday_hr_resources":1}"

arguments[0] = { "totalResults":138, "workday_search:workday_hr_resources":1}
```